# Installing a Python app when you do not have shell access?

Tags: shell

I know PHP but I do not know Python. I need to install a Python app to a shared hosting (where I do not have shell access). What steps should I follow?

I have: Apache, PHP, cgi-bin, Python, Perl, cPanel, FreeBSD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think you would use ftp to transfer it to the appropriate directory. Without more detail regarding what else might be necessary to accomplish the installation that's the best I can do.